# not able to generate JSON conversion classes when classes are extending base class

Tags: android, flutter, json-serializable

I am trying to create a `Model` and using `json_serializable` package in `Flutter` but the issue I am facing is when I try to serialize or auto-generate code for the class that is extending base class.

So in below class if i remove `AuthResponseData` it is throwing following error

> Could not generate `fromJson` code for `user`.

> late final UserData user;

For example,

```
@JsonSerializable()
class AuthResponseDataModel extends AuthResponseData {
  final UserDataModel user;
  final AccountDataModel accountData;

  AuthResponseDataModel(
    this.user,
    this.accountData,
  );

  factory AuthResponseDataModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$AuthResponseDataModelFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$AuthResponseDataModelToJson(this);
}
```

This is my entity class `AuthResponseData`

```
class AuthResponseData extends Equatable {
  late final UserData user;
  late final AccountData accountData;
  late final List<String> permissions;

  AuthResponseData({user, accountData, permissions});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [user, accountData, permissions];
}
```

Eventually, I want to typecase `AuthResponseDataModel` to `AuthResponse` but json_serializer is not allowing me to do so

Answer (score 1):

Resolved after referring

https://github.com/google/json_serializable.dart/issues/918

added following in a class

```
  @override
  UserDataModel get user => super.user as UserDataModel;
  @override
  AccountDataModel get accountData => super.accountData as AccountDataModel;
```